# Child process running forever even if parent crashes

Tags: node.js, spawn

I have written a console application for mac which should be run by node.
The following code is working.

```
childprocess = spawn(`./${processExecutable} \
                --log-path="${logs}"
            `, {
                cwd: pathToProcess,
                shell: true,
            })
```

However if I kill the node process, the child process continues to work. I would want him to stop if his parent is not present anymore.

I though a child process would do that automatically. Yet it just keeps running. If I restart the application It wants to start a new process while the other is still running.

How can I tell the child process to stop running if the parent is gone. Is this possible?

I tried adding `detached: false` but it would still keep running.

Comment: Parent being killed does not in itself cause child to be killed or exit. By default child's stdin,out,err are piped from and to parent; if child tries to read its stdin after parent dies it gets EOF, and _many_ programs exit when they read EOF, but it is possible this program doesn't read stdin or ignores EOF; if child tries to write (at OS level) stdout or stderr after parent death it gets SIGPIPE which by default will kill it, but it is possible this program doesn't write stdout/err (or only does buffered writes which don't go to OS), or catches/ignores SIGPIPE and ignores EPIPE.

Comment: Notice in the second paragraph of [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/child_process.html#optionsdetached) "Child processes may continue running after the parent exits regardless of whether they are detached or not."

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 do you have an idea how I could catch that on swift. So the child would know how to get the information its parent has died.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Swift (the language) at all. (Long ago I did know some about SWIFT the financial payments network, but that's obsolete now.)